# Segmentation fault; core dumped in my code c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault, stack

Every time I run it gives me this error Segmentation fault; core dumped;
I was trying to do a linkedStack in c++.
My code is:

Node.h

```
class Node {
public:
    Node(int element);
    const int& getElement()const;
    Node *getNext() const;
    void setNext(Node *e);
    Node(const Node& orig);
    virtual ~Node();

private:
    int element;
    Node *next;
};
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"
Node::Node(int element) {
    this->element=element;
}
const int& Node::getElement() const{
    return element;
}
Node * Node::getNext() const{
    return next;
}
void Node::setNext(Node *e){
    next=e;
}

Node::Node(const Node& orig) {
}

Node::~Node() {
}
```

LinkedStack.h

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "EmptyException.h"


class LinkedStack {
public:
    LinkedStack();
    int size() const;
    const Node& top() const;
    void push(const int& element);
    void pop();
    void print();
    LinkedStack(const LinkedStack& orig);
    virtual ~LinkedStack();
private:
    Node *front=NULL;
    int num_elements;
};
```

LinkedStack.cpp

```
#include "LinkedStack.h"
using namespace std;

LinkedStack::LinkedStack() {
}
int LinkedStack::size() const{
    return num_elements;
}
const Node& LinkedStack::top() const{
    return *front;
}
void LinkedStack::push(const int& element){
    Node *newfront=new Node(element);
    newfront->setNext(front);
    front=newfront;
    delete newfront;
    num_elements++;
}
void LinkedStack::pop(){
    if(num_elements==0){
        throw EmptyException();
    }
    else{
        Node *oldfront=front;
        front=front->getNext();
        num_elements--;
    }
}
void LinkedStack::print(){
    Node *temp=front;
    while(temp != __null){
        cout<<temp->getElement()<<endl;
        temp=temp->getNext();
    }
    cout<<""<<endl;
}

LinkedStack::LinkedStack(const LinkedStack& orig) {
}

LinkedStack::~LinkedStack() {
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "LinkedStack.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string menu[]={"1.Afegir","2.Eliminar","3.Mostrar","4.Sortir"};
    int opc,element;
    LinkedStack Stack;
    do{
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            cout<<menu[i]<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"Selecciona una opció"; cin>>opc; cout<<""<<endl;
        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                cout<<"Que vols afegir?... "; cin>>element; cout<<""<<endl;
                Stack.push(element);
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"Eliminant.... "<<endl;
                Stack.pop();
                break;
            case 3:
                Stack.print();
                break;
        }

    }while(opc!=4);

    return 0;
}
```

That's all.
When I try the first option(push) there's no problem but when I try to pop or print the stack it gives me the core dumped:segmentation fault error.

I'm thinking that the problem is about pointers(??) but I still dont get where or how.

If you could help it would be great ^^

Comment: `__null` - what is that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: `Node::Node(int)` leaves `next` uninitialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in the `push` method which cause segmentation method in the `pop`. In the following lines

```
newfront->setNext(front);
front=newfront;
delete newfront;
```

You set the next node to the pointed object by `front` which will be deleted to lines later, because the `front=newfront` set pointers to the same object.

The segmentation fault appears at line

```
front=front->getNext();
```

where a null object is dereferenced.

Comment: I understand where's the error but still dont know how to solve it :/
I tried some changes but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Following **Neil Butterworth**'s line of thought. What is `__null`? Is it a macro you defined?

**Use `nullptr`.**

```
void LinkedStack::print(){
    Node *temp = front;
    while(temp != nullptr){ // compare it against nullptr if this is Modern C++ (e.g. C++11). For previous C++ standards you can use temp != 0 or !temp
        cout << temp->getElement()<<endl;
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

---

Furthermore, as **aschepler** stated, your node constructor needs to set next to a null value.

```
Node::Node(int element) {
    this->element = element;
    this->next = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I changed my code using your advices but still not working like @ImrePiller said the problem is in push that create segmentation in pop  in front=front->getNext(): bcs of the front=newfront in push.
But no idea how to solve it.